# Which javascript features can I use in CiviCRM core?

Tags: developer, javascript, coding-standards

Does CiviCRM have an agreed-upon browser version to target for javascript features?

For example:

- Can I use [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) (IE 9+)?
- Can I use [`'use strict';`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) (IE 10+)?
- Can I use [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) (IE 11+)?
- Can I use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (Edge 12+)?
- Can I use [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) (Edge 13+)

Where should I draw the line?

And if I want to use something like Babel or TypeScript in an extension, what ES level should I target to keep my extension in line with CiviCRM core?

If CiviCRM *does* have a clear standard here, I would expect it to *change with time* and *be documented somewhere* — which means that the ideal answer to *this* question would point readers to that documentation.